# DFT zero-padding of signals starting before n=0

Tags: dft, zero-padding

If a signal starts before n=0, what part of the signal should be used to compute DFT after zero-padding? For example, x(n) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, where x(-2) = 1 and x(0) = 3. If this signal is zero-padded to N=8, the new signal would be x'(n) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0}, where, again, x'(-2) = 1 and x'(0)=3. However, to compute the DFT of this zero-padded signal x'(0), should I use {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0 , 0}, which starts with x'(-2), or should I use {3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2}, which starts with x'(0) with the first few terms (n<0) folded over? In terms of the DFT X(k), I think its magnitude would be the same for the two approaches, but its phase would be different, right?

Comment: but remember, since the DFT is circular, you can zero pad it on either end (or both ends) and the only difference in the DFT result will be a linear phase term corresponding to a rotation or circular-shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second one Tony... It yields the correct **implied** phase relationship.